# In optimization, what guarantees the existence of a minimizer?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Uniqueness of minimizer for a problem of the type $\min f(x), x \in \mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{C}$ convex, is that $f$ is strictly convex.

I am curious what is the theorem that gives existence of such a minimizer.

Comment: For existence, you need the additional hypothesis that $\mathcal{C}$ is compact as well as convex.

Comment: @ConnorHarris But compactness is only one assumption that guarantees existence of a minimizer. I wouldn't say it's needed, it's only one possible hypothesis. I think another common hypothesis which guarantees existence of a minimizer is that the convex function $f$ is coercive (and $\mathcal C$ is closed).

Comment: I might overlook something, but Isn't it a result of Fermat's theorem (stationary points)?